# Yii document generator not accepting docs command

Tags: php, yii, documentation-generation

I want to use Yii document generator, i have extracted the source in protected/commands.

When I try to run the command:

```
yiic docs check
```

it says:

```
Yii command runner (based on Yii v1.1.8)
Usage: c:\wamp\www\FRAMEW~1\yiic <command-name> [parameters...]

The following commands are available:
 - message
 - migrate
 - shell
 - webapp

To see individual command help, use the following:
   c:\wamp\www\FRAMEW~1\yiic help <command-name>
```

Do I need to edit any config to run `docs` command ?

Comment: Is this any help?: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/21924-how-to-use-yiic-while-generating-yii-like-documentation/

Comment: thanks @Madmartigan , i tried that but still tried that, but still same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a Command to your CConsoleApplication by adding it to the commandMap.
add this to your `protected/config/console.php`:

```
'commandMap' => array(
     'docs' => array(
        // alias of the path where you extracted the DocsCommand.php
        'class' => 'application.commands.DocsCommand',
      )
),
```

after that `yiic docs` will run DocsCommand and it also should appear in the list of available commands.

You have to do this in your console application config since CWebapplication and CConsoleApplication have many different properties you can set via config. `commandMap` in this example is a property of CConsoleApplication but not of CWebApplication so you can only define it in console app. Read more about configuration in [Yii's Definitive Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention#configuration)

Also if you have a look at the yiic.php in your applications protected path you will see it includes the `console.php` file:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yiic.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php';

require_once($yiic);
```

If you have configuration that should be the same for web and console, for example a database connection, you can put that into an own config file e.g. `config/db.php` and include it in both `config/main.php` and `config/console.php` like this:

```
'db' => include(dirname(__FILE__). '/db.php'),
```

Comment: can't I add it in main.php which is already being used as my web app config ?

Comment: added more details about configuration, hope it's all clear now?

Comment: Your solution looks gud and i tried also but same result. it only works if I put "docs" folder and "DocsCommand.php" in "framework/cli/commands", but then it tries to generate the docs of framework/cli directory, not the one where Im right now.

Comment: where did you take the command you are trying to use from? Do you want to build Yii docs with DocsCommand form Yii? That command is only suitable for the framework itself, you cannot use it for your own application code unless you modify it...

Comment: I made an app in Yii framework, so it means i can't generate docs for my app ?

Comment: Of course you can but not with that command... There are many tools out there like docblox, phpdox etc...

Comment: So I got it wrong :) I thought Yii has built in docs generator for yii apps. Im already using phpdocs. But anyways, thanks for you time and effort Cebe.